# Algorithm / data structure for resolving nested interpolated values in this example?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, interpolation

I am working on a compiler and one aspect currently is how to wait for interpolated variable names to be resolved. So I am wondering how to take a nested interpolated variable string and build some sort of simple data model/schema for unwrapping the evaluated string so to speak. Let me demonstrate.

Say we have a string like this:

```
foo{a{x}-{y}}-{baz{one}-{two}}-foo{c}
```

That has 1, 2, and 3 levels of nested interpolations in it. So essentially it should resolve something like this:

1. wait for `x`, `y`, `one`, `two`, and `c` to resolve.
2. when both `x` and `y` resolve, then resolve `a{x}-{y}` immediately.
3. when both `one` and `two` resolve, resolve `baz{one}-{two}`.
4. when `a{x}-{y}`, `baz{one}-{two}`, and `c` all resolve, then finally resolve the whole expression.

I am shaky on my understanding of the logic flow for handling something like this, wondering if you could help solidify/clarify the general algorithm (high level pseudocode or something like that). Mainly just looking for how I would structure the data model and algorithm so as to progressively evaluate when the pieces are ready.

I'm starting out trying and it's not clear what to do next:

```
{
  dependencies: [
    {
      path: [x]
    },
    {
      path: [y]
    }
  ],
  parent: {
    dependency: a{x}-{y} // interpolated term
    parent: {
      dependencies: [
        {

        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Some sort of tree is probably necessary, but I am having trouble figuring out what it might look like, wondering if you could shed some light on that with some pseudocode (or JavaScript even).

- watch the leaf nodes at first
- then, when the children of a node are completed, propagate upward to resolving the next parent node. This would mean once `x` and `y` are done, it could resolve `a{x}-{y}`, but then wait until the other nodes are ready before doing the final top-level evaluation.

You can just simulate it by sending "events" to the system theoretically, like:

```
ready('y')
ready('c')
ready('x')
ready('a{x}-{y}')

function ready(variable) {
  if ()
}
```

...actually that may not work, not sure how to handle the interpolated nodes in a hacky way like that. But even a high level description of how to solve this would be helpful.

```
export type SiteDependencyObserverParentType = {
  observer: SiteDependencyObserverType
  remaining: number
}

export type SiteDependencyObserverType = {
  children: Array<SiteDependencyObserverType>
  node: LinkNodeType
  parent?: SiteDependencyObserverParentType
  path: Array<string>
}
```

*(What I'm currently thinking, some TypeScript)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach in JavaScript:

- Parse the input string to create a Node instance for each `{}` term, and create parent-child dependencies between the nodes.
- Collect the leaf Nodes of this tree as the tree is being constructed: group these leaf nodes by their identifier. Note that the same identifier could occur multiple times in the input string, leading to multiple Nodes. If a variable `x` is resolved, then all Nodes with that name (the group) will be resolved.
- Each node has a `resolve` method to set its final value
- Each node has a `notify` method that any of its child nodes can call in order to notify it that the child has been resolved with a value. This may (or may not yet) lead to a cascading call of `resolve`.
- In a demo, a timer is set up that at every tick will resolve a randomly picked variable to some number

I think that in your example, `foo`, and `a` might be functions that need to be called, but I didn't elaborate on that, and just considered them as literal text that does not need further treatment. It should not be difficult to extend the algorithm with such function-calling features.

```js
class Node {
    constructor(parent) {
        this.source = ""; // The slice of the input string that maps to this node
        this.texts = []; // Literal text that's not part of interpolation
        this.children = []; // Node instances corresponding to interpolation
        this.parent = parent; // Link to parent that should get notified when this node resolves
        this.value = undefined; // Not yet resolved
    }
    isResolved() {
        return this.value !== undefined;
    }
    resolve(value) {
        if (this.isResolved()) return; // A node is not allowed to resolve twice: ignore
        console.log(`Resolving "${this.source}" to "${value}"`);
        this.value = value;
        if (this.parent) this.parent.notify();
    }
    notify() {
        // Check if all dependencies have been resolved
        let value = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++) {
            const child = this.children[i];
            if (!child.isResolved()) { // Not ready yet
                console.log(`"${this.source}" is getting notified, but not all dependecies are ready yet`);
                return; 
            }
            value += this.texts[i] + child.value;
        }
        console.log(`"${this.source}" is getting notified, and all dependecies are ready:`);
        this.resolve(value + this.texts.at(-1));
    }
}

function makeTree(s) {
    const leaves = {}; // nodes keyed by atomic names (like "x" "y" in the example)
    const tokens = s.split(/([{}])/);
    let i = 0; // Index in s
    
    function dfs(parent=null) {
        const node = new Node(parent);
        const start = i;
        while (tokens.length) {
            const token = tokens.shift();
            i += token.length;
            if (token == "}") break;
            if (token == "{") {
                node.children.push(dfs(node));
            } else {
                node.texts.push(token);
            }
        }
        node.source = s.slice(start, i - (tokens.length ? 1 : 0));
        if (node.children.length == 0) { // It's a leaf
            const label = node.texts[0];
            leaves[label] ??= []; // Define as empty array if not yet defined
            leaves[label].push(node);
        }
        return node;
    }
    
    dfs();
    
    return leaves;
}

// ------------------- DEMO --------------------
let s = "foo{a{x}-{y}}-{baz{one}-{two}}-foo{c}";
const leaves = makeTree(s);

// Create a random order in which to resolve the atomic variables:
function shuffle(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [array[j], array[i]] = [array[i], array[j]];
    }
    return array;
}
const names = shuffle(Object.keys(leaves));

// Use a timer to resolve the variables one by one in the given random order
let index = 0;
function resolveRandomVariable() {
    if (index >= names.length) return; // all done
    console.log("\n---------------- timer tick --------------");
    const name = names[index++];
    console.log(`Variable ${name} gets a value: "${index}". Calling resolve() on the connected node instance(s):`);
    for (const node of leaves[name]) node.resolve(index);
    setTimeout(resolveRandomVariable, 1000);
}    
setTimeout(resolveRandomVariable, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

your idea of building a dependency tree it's really likeable.
Anyway I tryed to find a solution as simplest possible.
Even if it already works, there are many optimizations possible, take this just as proof of concept.

The background idea it's produce a `List` of Strings which you can read in **order** where each element it's what you need to solve progressively. Each element might be mandatory to solve something that come next in the `List`, hence for the overall expression. Once you solved all the chunks you have all pieces to solve your original expression.

It's written in Java, I hope it's understandable.

```java
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Objects;

    public class StackOverflow {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            String exp = "foo{a{x}-{y}}-{baz{one}-{two}}-foo{c}";
            List<String> chunks = expToChunks(exp);

            //it just reverse the order of the list
            Collections.reverse(chunks);
            System.out.println(chunks);
            //output -> [c, two, one, baz{one}-{two}, y, x, a{x}-{y}]

        }

        public static List<String> expToChunks(String exp) {
            List<String> chunks = new ArrayList<>();


            //this first piece just find the first inner open parenthesys and its relative close parenthesys
            int begin = exp.indexOf("{") + 1;

            int numberOfParenthesys = 1;
            int end = -1;
            for(int i = begin; i < exp.length(); i++) {
                char c = exp.charAt(i);
                if (c == '{') numberOfParenthesys ++;
                if (c == '}') numberOfParenthesys --;
                if (numberOfParenthesys == 0) {
                    end = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            //this if put an end to recursive calls
            if(begin > 0 && begin < exp.length() && end > 0) {
                //add the chunk to the final list
                String substring = exp.substring(begin, end);
                chunks.add(substring);

                //remove from the starting expression the already considered chunk
                String newExp = exp.replace("{" + substring + "}", "");

                //recursive call for inner element on the chunk found
                chunks.addAll(Objects.requireNonNull(expToChunks(substring)));

                //calculate other chunks on the remained expression
                chunks.addAll(Objects.requireNonNull(expToChunks(newExp)));
            }


            return chunks;
        }


    }
```

Some details on the code:

The following piece find the `begin` and the `end` index of the first outer chunk of expression. The background idea is: **in a valid expression the number of open parenthesys must be equal to the number of closing parenthesys. The count of open(+1) and close(-1) parenthesys can't ever be negative.**
So using that simple loop once I find the **count of parenthesys** to be 0, I also found the first chunk of the expression.

```java
    int begin = exp.indexOf("{") + 1;

    int numberOfParenthesys = 1;
    int end = -1;
    for(int i = begin; i < exp.length(); i++) {
         char c = exp.charAt(i);
         if (c == '{') numberOfParenthesys ++;
         if (c == '}') numberOfParenthesys --;
         if (numberOfParenthesys == 0) {
             end = i;
             break;
         }
    }
```

The if condition provide validation on the `begin` and `end` indexes and stop the recursive call when no more chunks can be found on the remained expression.

```java
    if(begin > 0 && begin < exp.length() && end > 0) {
        ...
    }
```